# How to disable global ASLR setting on Windows Server 2016 Essentials?

Tags: windows-server-2016

I'm trying to deploy some old custom software on the computer running Windows Server 2016 Essentials. Previously it used to run on Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit, without any issues.

The software in question provides interface for the hardware used on site. Unfortunately the software vendor is no longer in business, and replacing it with a competitor product would cost many thousands of $$. So I will need to find a solution in changing settings in Windows first.

I did some search and [this page](http://everything-techie-under-the-sun.blogspot.com/2009/12/why-delphi-bde-applications-sometimes.html) exactly explains the issues I'm seeing.  The software in question uses a very old Borland Database Engine (BDE) that is not compatible with Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) and we're getting sporadic crashes and memory errors.

So my question -- can I disable ASLR in Windows on a global level? At least for testing purposes to see if it solves the issue.

And, my second question -- what else can I change in Windows Server 2016 to make it run more like Windows 7 Pro that may be causing issues for this software?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean about making Server 2016 run more like Win 7 Pro? Besides one of these being a server OS and the other a desktop OK, they are also two major generations apart from each other and there are and will be deep and substantial differences between the two. Knowing what you're specifically looking for would help get better answers.

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560993/how-do-you-disable-aslr-address-space-layout-randomization-on-windows-7-x64

Comment: @music2myear: Yes, I know that. My point was to see what difference is between starting processes on each OS. Also concerning the link that Peter showed, I did find it. Unfortunately neither that registry setting, nor the EMET tool seem to work anymore since `Windows 8.1` or `Server 2012`. So it seems like the answer is, no, one can't disable ASLR on a Server 2016 OS.

Comment: That question is then getting into the architecture of the OS at a rather deep level, I think, and probably well beyond an answer that could be provided here. And wow, BDE, talk about a blast from the past. Last place I worked had several large and old CAM machines that ran NT3 on their controllers. Thankfully, there was third-party software that could talk with them and the other controllers around the environment and that ran on modern OSes, but for the controllers themselves we kept copies of hard drives we could swap into the controllers if one failed with all the old software setup.

Comment: Frankly, in your position, I'd tell those who sign the checks that the thousands of dollars are kinda needed at this point. You're going to have to pay it sometime, and you may as well get it done and out of the way. But, that's just my opinion.

Comment: @music2myear: Yeah, thanks. That's what I told them. Unfortunately like anything else in running a business, if you can squeeze by by cutting a corner or two in existing infrastructure (molding Windows to BDE, or sticking with an old OS in this case) they will do it. So we'll probably have to downgrade to an older version of the OS where we can disable ASLR.